# How to print source code lines in python logger

Tags: python, debugging, logging

Is there some relatively simple way to programmatically include source code lines to python logger report. For example...

```
import logging

def main():
    something_is_not_right = True
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format=('%(filename)s: '    
                                '%(levelname)s: '
                                '%(funcName)s(): '
                                '%(lineno)d:\t'
                                '%(message)s')
                        )

    if something_is_not_right == True:
        logging.debug('some way to get previous line of source code here?')
```

So that output would look like this.

```
example.py: DEBUG: main(): 14:       if something_is_not_right == True:
```

Comment: Doesn't that already do just that?

Comment: @marcog Sorry for my inability to explain my problem more clearly. TryPyPy and unutbu understood what I was looking for. Hopefully their answers explain what I was after.

Comment: I also made the same assumption as marcog and couldn't understand what the problem was. Perhaps edit your question to read "programmatically include _arbitrary_ source code lines, not just the line that logs"

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
import inspect
import logging
import linecache

def main():
    something_is_not_right = True
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format=('%(filename)s: '    
                                '%(levelname)s: '
                                '%(funcName)s(): '
                                '%(lineno)d:\t'
                                '%(message)s')
                        )

    if something_is_not_right:
        logging.debug(linecache.getline(
            __file__,
            inspect.getlineno(inspect.currentframe())-1))

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

yields

```
test.py: DEBUG: main(): 18:     if something_is_not_right == True:
```

Comment: Wow, this is crying out for simple ____file____ and ____line____ (without any of the inspect/currentframe stuff).

Answer (score 5):

Just because I saw unutbu try something similar, here's the code I came up with (too late to post otherwise):

```
import logging, sys

# From logging.py
def currentframe():
    """Return the frame object for the caller's stack frame."""
    try:
        raise Exception
    except:
        return sys.exc_traceback

f = open(__file__.rstrip('c'))
owncode = f.readlines()
f.close()

def main():
    something_is_not_right = True
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                        format=('%(filename)s: '
                                '%(levelname)s: '
                                '%(funcName)s(): '
                                '%(lineno)d:\t'
                                '%(message)s')
                        )

    if something_is_not_right == True:
        prev = owncode[currentframe().tb_frame.f_back.f_lineno - 2]
        logging.debug('previous line of source code here:\n%s' % prev)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```